# Javascript date toLocaleString ignores locale

Tags: javascript, browser, locale

I have en_GB as locale on both my system and my browser.

[browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0BYf.png)

[system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOcCo.png)

When I run `(new Date()).toLocaleString()` in the browser console I get "12/1/2021, 1:56:32 PM" aka the en_US format. However, if I set the locale via Chromium Dev Tools Sensors tab to en_GB and reload the page, the function returns "01/12/2021, 14:05:02" aka the proper en_GB formatting.

[Overriding locale with Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQL8R.png)

So my questions is whether or not this is an issue with my system/browser. If it's not an issue with my configuraiton, then how why does that dev tools feature fix the issue? How exactly does it change the global javascript values and why doesn't the browser set those automatically according to my default language?

I am aware of workarounds such as passing the `navigator.language` manually as an argument to `toLocaleString` function or using a library like moment or dayjs to manage my dates and formatting, but this questions just about the unpredictable behaviour of `toLocaleString` as I have described above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I have had `export LANG=en_US.utf8` in my `.bashrc`. Since it is apparently sourced before starting any program on my system, the browsers used en_US instead of my actual system language.